# table inheritance: design suggestions? 

Tags: entity-framework, oop, design-patterns

Any suggestions on clean ways to solve this design issue?

```
public class Task
{
    public User Assignee
    public User Assigner
}

public class User
{
    public string Name
}
```

So a task has two users. But now we want to add support for groups...

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name
    public IEnumberable<User> Users
}
```

And we want the task to be able to handle a group as an Assignee

```
public class Task
{
    public User/Group Assignee
    public User Assigner
}
```

When I think about inheritance here. Group "is a type of" User doesn't meet this LSP because Group "is not replaceable by" User

I'm using Entity Framework (model first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group` is not `User`. That is incorrect modelling. If you need inheritance define a new top level abstract entity - for example `Identity` and derive `User` and `Group` from this entity:

```
public class Task
{
    public Identity Assignee
    public User Assigner
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not have

```
public class Task
{
    public Group Assignee
    public User Assigner
}
```

where a `Group` with a single user replaces a single `User`?

Comment: In such case you don't need `Group` at all and you can use `ICollection<User>`.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka why is it different in this case? What is **this** case? I doubt that's his whole code.

Comment: If you work with additional entity like Group you probably expect some additional fields in this entity. I doubt that it is only collection of users but in your example it really is. If a group has some additional (mandatory) properties your example will lead to creating and maintaining a lot of additional "virtual" groups. From relational concept it can be better - it will have better performance than inheritance handled by EF but from modeling perspective it will lead to creating entities just to satisfy the model.

Comment: @Ladislav - Yes. All of those entities have more properties. I simplified it for the question. I'm leaning towards the inheritance route. User is a very fundamental piece of our application. It would be a huge change to make User = Group of one. And in most places, wouldn't make sense.